# Removing empty xmlns element after XSL based transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, xml-namespaces

Recently, I have been working with a Data Transformation tool that uses XSL to modify the format of input data. I have recently [been having problems with the namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610014/converting-xml-into-string-cdata-in-xslt), and now I am having a new problem, caused by the solution to the previous question.

The correct xmlns is stored within the parent element, but then the first child element (the only first level child node) contains an attribute `xmlns=""`. I have found a few similar questions, but the problem/method of implementation is different enough to stop me from applying the changes directly. Does anyone know how I can stop that attribute from being applied to the child data? I have thought about going down the path I had gone down before (by serializing the XML and then doing string operations to fix it), but the required serialization functions only exist in xpath 3, and the transformation server I am using only support up to xpath 2, which sadly I have no say over :(

I am using Map Force to build the XSL transformations, and as such, cannot simple edit the XSL (as it will be overwritten by map force), but I am confident that I could apply an XSL change to Map Force.

**A SNIPPET OF XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:core="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="core xs fn">
    <xsl:template name="core:firstCharacter">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="core:tokenize-by-length-internal">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_SwiftMessages" as="node()?" select="SwiftMessages"/>
        <xformResult xmlns="urn:...">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" select="'urn:... OutputInterface/xformResult.xsd'"/>
            <xformResultRecord>
                <xformResultData>
                    <Document>
                        <!-- REMAINDER OF FAIRLY STANDARD CODE -->
                    </Document>
                </xformResultData>
            </xformResultRecord>
        </xformResult>
    </xsl:template>
```

The `urn:...`'s are the references to the specifications of the output file, and the `xformResult.xsd` is the Schema that outputs the file.

The transformer XML file then sent back to the handler program where all elements within `<xformResultData>` are then outputted to a file. This is where the problem is. The output file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:..." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Cstmr xmlns="">
        <!-- REMAINDER OF GENERATED XML -->
    </Cstmr>
</Document>
```

As you can see, the first level child of `Document` (`Cstmr`) has had `xmlns=""` added to the element by the transformer output. When I have tested this with Map Force, this is not included, but it is in the output from the xform tool. The xform tool is based upon SAXON, and the calls to it are fairly standard XML functions.

Comment: What does your XSLT look like that is producing the empty namespace?

Comment: You're not showing us the code that generates the Cstmr element, so it's hard to advise you how to change it. Whatever the code is, its generating a Cstmr element in no namespace, when it should be generating the element in the urn:... namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Namespace declarations are *not* attributes, even though they look the same. If you have `xmlns=""` appearing on an element in your output then it means that you added an element with no namespace to the tree at a point where there was a default namespace already in force.  In order to output such a structure the serializer must countermand that default with `xmlns=""`.

To fix this you need to create the elements in the correct namespace to start with.  For example, suppose your input XML is something like

```
<example xmlns="http://example.com">
  <child1/>
</example>
```

and you want to replace `child1` with `child2`.  The following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace children of the document element with child2 -->
  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <child2 /><!-- child2 is in no namespace -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would produce a result like the one you're seeing

```
<example xmlns="http://example.com">
  <child2 xmlns=""/>
</example>
```

because the stylesheet creates the child2 element in no namespace.  But if you add `xmlns="http://example.com"` to the *stylesheet*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://example.com">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace children of the document element with child2 -->
  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <child2 /><!-- child2 is now in the http://example.com namespace -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then it will produce the correct result

```
<example xmlns="http://example.com">
  <child2 />
</example>
```

If you don't want to add the default declaration to the whole stylesheet you can localise it just on the template that is responsible for creating the output element, or indeed on the element itself, e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="/*/*" xmlns="http://example.com">
    <child2/>
  </xsl:template>
```

---

Edit: referring to your specific example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:core="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="core xs fn">
    <xsl:template name="core:firstCharacter">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="core:tokenize-by-length-internal">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_SwiftMessages" as="node()?" select="SwiftMessages"/>
        <xformResult xmlns="urn:...">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" select="'urn:... OutputInterface/xformResult.xsd'"/>
            <xformResultRecord>
                <xformResultData>
                    <Document>
                        <!-- example of code that might be in here -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$var1_SwiftMessages/Customer" />
                    </Document>
                </xformResultData>
            </xformResultRecord>
        </xformResult>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer">
        <Cstmr>
            <!-- contents of Cstmr element -->
        </Cstmr>
    </xsl:template>
```

The key thing to understand here is that the namespace bindings that apply to literal result elements are those that are in force at the relevant place in the *stylesheet* when treated as a plain XML document.  The `xformResult`, `xformResultRecord`, `xformResultData` and `Document` elements are in the `urn:...` namespace because that is declared as the default on the `xformResult` element in the stylesheet, but the `Cstmr` element in the Customer template is *not* in a namespace.  If instead you move the `xmlns` declaration up from the `xformResult` to the `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="urn:..." xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:core="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="core xs fn">
    <xsl:template name="core:firstCharacter">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="core:tokenize-by-length-internal">
        ...
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_SwiftMessages" as="node()?" select="SwiftMessages"/>
        <xformResult>
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" select="'urn:... OutputInterface/xformResult.xsd'"/>
            <xformResultRecord>
                <xformResultData>
                    <Document>
                        <!-- example of code that might be in here -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$var1_SwiftMessages/Customer" />
                    </Document>
                </xformResultData>
            </xformResultRecord>
        </xformResult>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer">
        <Cstmr>
            <!-- contents of Cstmr element -->
        </Cstmr>
    </xsl:template>
```

then this will put all the unprefixed literal result elements into the `urn:...` namespace, including the `Cstmr`.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a problem elsewhere in your transformation (or input data). It is **not** a matter of serialization.

The two examples below has different meaning. In the first one `body` has the *xhtml* namespace, as it is the default, set on the root element.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the second example you override the default namespace and explicitly say that the `body` node is from the namespace *empty string*. Which is a different object from the one ih the `xhtml` namespace.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body xmlns="">
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

If doing an other transformation is an option, the following XSLT will apply the parent's namespace (in fact the namespace of the closest suitable ancestor) to elements with empty namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template priority="2" match="*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="namespace-uri()=''">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri(ancestor::*[namespace-uri()!=''][1])}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template priority="1" match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit2:**

Here is a permissive schema which will validate anything, you only need the name and namespace (for the schema's targetNamespace attribute) of the root element. For the demo I followed the *html* example above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="html">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That is pretty much the problem I am experiencing (but instead of html, a propriety xml form). The `xmlns=""` within your `body` tag is what I am seeing on mine. But how can I stop Map Force from forcibly inserting `xmlns=""`? From what I have found on the internet, it seems to be that the template that is populating the data is not in a namespace, so it is getting inserted into the default namespace (which is `""`), so I need to find a way to stop Map Force from thinking the namespace is different when it should inherit it

Comment: @cgoddard Sharing your generated XSLT might help. (If it is not confidential.)

Comment: super confidential (apparently banks seem to think that information shared within their community cant get out to the wider world to such an extend that to get the spec, you need to sign an 200 page NDA...). at any rate, the xslt is huge, the full mapping is 57k and over 2000 lines long

Comment: Ooh, that looks nifty. I can create another step in the process (currently, there are 4 and this is the final transformation), so I could put this on the end directly as an XSL transformation (without mapforce) and use this to remove any empty namespaces. Thank you, I'll let you know how it works out

Comment: Dammit, already given you a +1, if only SE allowed for more than just +1 and -1 for judging (i know there is mark as answer, but thats only for when it works)

Comment: @cgoddard I can wait... ;)

Comment: Annoyingly, I cannot create a new step, as the `xmlns` "attribute" (i know it isn't an attribute, but it is easier to call it that for the moment), because I cannot modify the XSD to allow for an xmlns element, and it will not validate because `xmlns` has an invalid value and breaks the transformer. Looks like I will need to fix it within that step :s Nice idea though

Comment: @cgoddard "I cannot modify the XSD to allow for an xmlns element" - a schema doesn't know or care about the names and locations of specific `xmlns` declarations in the XML document, it only cares that the elements are in the correct namespace.

Comment: Oh it does, every time I try to include an allowance for the existence of an attribute labelled "xmlns", my xml editor has a hissy fit saying "xmlns is a reserved name", however, if I don't include it, then the transformer has a hissy fit saying that an unexpected attribute occurred which did not match the xsd, its very annoying, unless its the last step (the xsd validation process happens at the beginning of each step)

Comment: @cgoddard Maybe you can use a permissive XSD which allows anything for this middle step and validate with the real one at the end of the process.

Comment: @cgoddard you really must stop thinking of `xmlns` declarations as if they were attributes - fix the XSLT to generate the _elements_ in the correct namespace and the superfluous namespace declarations will disappear as they're no longer required.

Comment: I know its not an attribute, but that is the problem. How do I ensure that an element is being created within the same namespace as the parent element without it falling back to the default (in this case "")

Comment: @cgoddard by having the right namespace declarations in place at the right points in the _stylesheet_, as I explain in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20615068/592139).

Comment: @cgoddard in your case it may be sufficient to simply move the `xmlns="urn:..."` from the `xformResult` element up onto the `xsl:stylesheet` instead, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing more of your code.

Comment: @cgoddard I added a schema if you need to validate the inconsistent document during the process.